# AlertJS modal title doesn't show

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

I need to show both alert message and alertmodal title. Currently, only AlertJS shows. When I try and add a title after the second comma the modal shows the message as the title. How can I have both a message and title? Is this possible?

AlertJS modal title not displaying:

```js
$('#confirmSingles').click(function() {
  alertify.confirm('Are you sure you want to confirm all listed singles?', function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'api/singles/confirm'
    }).always(function(data) {
      handleConfirmResponse(data);
    });
  });
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Alertify documentation](https://alertifyjs.com/guide.html#defaults), the library uses a global `alertify.defaults` object to store settings. The title value is stored within this object. To change the title, simply provide a new value for the `alertify.defaults.glossary.title` property:

```js
$('#confirmSingles').click(function() {
  alertify.defaults.glossary.title = "Your title here...";

  alertify.confirm('Are you sure you want to confirm all listed singles?', function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'api/singles/confirm'
    }).always(function(data) {
      // handleConfirmResponse(data);
      console.log('todo...');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.13.1/build/alertify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.13.1/build/css/alertify.min.css" />

<button id="confirmSingles">Confirm</button>
```